# Why my simple ajax call to a controller method is not working?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am just starting in ASP .NET MVC.
I'm trying to call a POST action method using jQuery ajax as below, but my Controller method is not getting hit.
below js function is invoked by onclick() of the button.

```
function ValidateLogin() {
    var dat = {};
    dat.Username = $("#username_input").val();
    dat.Password = $("#password_input").val();
    dat.PreviousActionName = '';
    if (dat.Password != '' && dat.Username != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Login/ValidateLogin',        //Tried '@Url.Action("ValidateLogin", "Login")' as well
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(dat),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () {
                alert("Success!");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = xhr.responseText;
                alert("Failed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my LoginModel

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        public String Username { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }
        public String PreviousActionName { get; set; }
    }
```

and the LoginController:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Login
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ValidateLogin(LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            String Username = loginModel.Username;
            String Password = loginModel.Password;
            return View("Login");
        }
    }
```

**Note: I locally hosted this project in IIS with the name 'Client'.**
So the initial URL will be http://localhost/Client
when I used '/Login/ValidateLogin' in AJAX url, final URL is http://localhost/Login/ValidateLogin and in this case I'm getting the http://localhost/Login/ValidateLogin cannot be found in browser console. So I changed the url in ajax to 'Client/Login/ValidateLogin'. Now it's just error function in ajax.

Here is my RouteConfig class if it helps:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong. Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Now it's just error function in ajax."_ - And that _"error function"_ might tell you the problem if you would check its arguments instead of only alerting "Failed".

Comment: @Andreas I debugged in the browser. All the parameters of the error function is 'undefined'.

Comment: If jQuery triggers the `error` callback then none of them will be `undefined`

Comment: I'm sorry, How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntax

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Client/Login/ValidateLogin',        
            type: 'POST',
            data: dat,
            success: function (result) { 
               ///  $('#result').html(result);
                alert("Success!");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = xhr.responseText;
                alert(err);
            }
        });
```

and when you use Ajax you have to use div and  partialview instead of view to return

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only changed the url to 'Client/Login/ValidateLogin'. Now my post method is getting hit, but I'm still getting the Failed alert from error in ajax. I'll use partialview instead as you suggested.

Comment: You have to try to use the whole code, not just to change url

Comment: I've tried and now I returned ContentResult from the controller method and in the success function of the ajax I'm navigating to my desired location. All this time I couldn't see that I didn't write anything in the Success function other than the alert.

Comment: Is your ajax call in the controller working now?

Comment: I took a break. Yes ajax call is working perfectly, only in chrome. In Firefox, Controller POST method is invoked but I am still getting the error alert. I checked in the browser tools and checked the response in Network section. The status is 200 and it is OK. but after this I'm getting some JSON Log starting with abort in browser console. Event Listener Breakpoints Log is enabled. JSON Log in the console details [img](https://imgur.com/RbfqcqI)